# Bad Review Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I came accross [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/14222035) and failed.

> I'm having troubles installing nokogiri (1.6.8.1) on Mac OS Sierra
>   10.12
>
> I tried using brew install libxml2 libxslt and then referencing
>   install directories using command line options but it doesn't helped

To me, it falls into the category "must include a specific problem or error", e.g. defining what *troubles* mean.

I think this audit should be removed, because it is too vague.

Comment: In *this case*, it probably shouldn't be closed - enough people had this problem, myself included, that specific error messages aren't really necessary and the answers provided are adequate. I do agree that it's a horrible audit, though.

Comment: After seeing the good responses, I agree the question should not be closed. But as a reviewer, you don't see the responses.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRi6f.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, that was a problem that many many people had with a new IOS release, and thus lots of people found the question and answer helpful. Doesn't look too ambiguous to me, personally, but it makes for a horrid audit.

Audits are selected automatically, based on upvotes, lack of downvotes/close votes and how long they've been on the site.

The question has since recieved a downvote and is thus no longer eligible as an audit.

Thats the best way to handle these. If you downvote and/or close vote a question that you feel was unfairly used as an audit, it will prevent that question from being used as an audit again (for Known-Good audits, that is)

Comment: Are you advocating to downvote a question for a reason other than the question being bad? In this particular case, perhaps the two arguably coincide. But I have a different case in mind, where a supposedly bad answer is used as an audit, even though it is the only correct answer to a perfectly fine question. Should I downvote the question anyway?